# Python class attribute inside of class attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a class called Customer. This class should contain the attributes self.name, self.address, self.customernumber. The attribute self.address should contain more information, that vary in-between the different customers. This information consist of the customers street, post code,city and invoice address. Is there a possibility, to treat these points I just named, as sub-attributes of self.address and how can I do that ?

```
class Customer:
    def __init__ (self, name, address, custnumber):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address:
              self.address.street
              self.address.postcode
              self.address.city
              self.address.invoiceaddress
        self.custnumber = customer

cust1 = Customer(Person Example, address: (street1, city1,invoiceaddress, ... ) , 124421)
```

Comment: not quite clear what you want to do, are you looking for a dict?

Comment: You seem to understand the idea of a class since you created one for `Customer`. Why don't you create one for `Address`? or, at the very least, make `self.address` a `dict`

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but if I create a new class for Address, I wouldn't be able to assign values to it only by using the equation cust1 = Customer/Address(..), correct? Wouldn't I have to severely define a cust1 = Customer() an address1 = Address() for each customer ? And even then how can I clearly relate the customer to the address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case for composition. You create an `Address` class, and pass an instance as the second argument to `Customer`.

```
class Address:
    def __init__(self, street: str, postcode: str, city: str, invoiceaddress: str):
        self.street = street
        self.postcode = postcode
        self.city = city
        self.invoiceaddress = invoiceaddress


class Customer:
    def __init__ (self, name: str, address: Address, custnumber: str):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.custnumber = customer

cus1 = Customer("bob", Address("main st", "Springfield", "..."), 1)
```